# How to delete duplicate values in list and average corresponding values in other list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a somewhat large set of experimental points, lets say *x* and *y*, each stored in its respective list. It just so happens that some values of *x* are repeated and correspond to different values of y. What's the best way to get rid of the duplicate *x* values and average the corresponding *y* values?

Example:

```py
x = [1,1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3,4]

x_new = [1,2,3]
y_new = [1.5,3,4]
```

PS: Sorry for bad titling or formatting.

Comment: Are these guaranteed to be exactly equal? I.e. `x[i] == x[j]` holds even if they are `float` objects? Or they are considered equal within some tolerance?

Comment: @a_guest They are guaranteed to be equal

Comment: Are you okay with using third-party packages like `pandas`?

Comment: @a_guest `pandas` is something I've been wanting to learn for a while, so I would really like to see your approach with it, please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` to collect and average the `y` values:

```
from collections import defaultdict
xs = [1,1,2,3]
ys = [1,2,3,4]

# dictionary autofilled with list for missing values
by_x = defaultdict(list)

# collect all ys per x
for x, y in zip(xs,ys): by_x[x].append(y)

# average ys per x
result = {x: sum(y) / len(y) for x, y in by_x.items()}

new_xs = result.keys() # dict_keys([1, 2, 3])
new_ys = result.values() # dict_values([1.5, 3.0, 4.0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `dict` with the x values as the keys, and the y values as the value. Loop over the `list`, add the associated y value to the current average, and divide by 2.

Then make 2 lists once it's all done. The x values are from the keys, and the y values are the values.

```py
x = [1,1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3,4]

values = {}
for x_value, y_value in zip(x, y):
    new_y = (values.get(x_value, y_value) + y_value) / 2
    if new_y.is_integer():
        new_y = int(new_y)
    values[x_value] = new_y

x_new = list(values)
y_new = list(values.values())

print("x_new:", x_new)
print("y_new:", y_new)
```

Output:

```
x_new: [1, 2, 3]
y_new: [1.5, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for grouping by the x-values and then taking the `mean` along the y-values:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(zip([1,1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]), columns=list('xy'))
>>> df
   x  y
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  2  3
3  3  4
>>> df.groupby('x').mean()
     y
x     
1  1.5
2  3.0
3  4.0
```